# How can I open a file on the desktop with my program?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to open a file with my program, but I don't know how.

Here's what I mean:

[image]

I searched on internet and I found nothing (only the "Open with" method and that's not what I want).

Is it possible to make something like that?

Answer (score 0):

This is done through the "Windows Registry":

Create a new `.reg` file with the following content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Python Script\command]
@="py -3 my_script.py %1"
```

Replace `my_script.py` with the full path to your python script.

`%1` will be replaced with the path of the file you have clicked.

Then run the script and it should add your program to the context menu.

Comment: I did it, even if i don't really undarstand, and on what I have to click, but then how do I read the file and do what I want to do whit the file in python? (Thank you)